# Bogoliubov spectrum of pair-density wave is not particle-hole symmetric

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, superconductivity

I am currently reading this review article about pair-density wave: https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-conmatphys-031119-050711.

There is a statement that I am not sure whether I understand. It is said that the Bogoliubov spectrum is not particle–hole symmetric, see Figure 3 in the paper and the sentences right above it.

My understanding is that when we write down the mean-field Hamiltonian for a pair-density wave state, we will have pairing terms like

\begin{equation}
\sum_{\mathbf{k}} c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{k},\sigma} \Delta_{\sigma,\sigma'}(\mathbf{k}) c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{Q},\sigma'},
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{Q}$ is the momentum of the pair-density wave function. However, if we are working with a lattice model and if $\mathbf{Q}$ is commensurate with the lattice constant, then we can always do a folding of the Brillouin zone such that the resulting Bogoliubov spectrum is particle-hole symmetric. The number of bands in the Bogoliubov spectrum will surely increase when we do the folding. Even though $\mathbf{Q}$ is incommensurate with the lattice constant, we can still approximate the $\mathbf{Q}$ by a rational number and perform the Brillouin zone folding, although the unit cell in this case will be very huge. In other words, when we have done a proper Brillouin zone folding, the BdG Hamiltonian will have the particle-hole symmetry (or particle-hole constraint) by construction, which is represent as Eq. (3.4) of this RMP: https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.88.035005.

From another viewpoint in real-space, we can just Fourier transform the above pairing interaction and write it in terms of real-space basis
\begin{equation}
\sum_{a,b} c^{\dagger}_{a} \Delta_{ab} c_{b}^{\dagger},
\end{equation}
where $a$ and $b$ are indices for real-space basis. As we know from Eqs. (2.17)-(2.21) in the same RMP: https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.88.035005, as long as we have a pairing term like the one I wrote above, we can always write it in terms of BdG form. And whenever we write it using BdG form, particle-hole symmetry must be there by construction.

And so, (1) from the momentum-space representation with proper Brillouin zone folding, the Bogoliubov spectrum will be particle-hole symmetric, and (2) from the real-space representation, we can also directly see that particle-hole symmetry is there by construction.

Therefore, I get a bit confused about why people say that particle-hole symmetry is broken in a pair-density wave state, which to my understanding is one type of superconductor and particle-hole symmetry is there by construction when we write it in BdG form. I guess maybe it is just that I didn't get the proper definition of "particle-hole breaking" in the content of pair-density wave.